# query satisying the given condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am using sql server management studio 2012. Please tae a minute or two to understand this problem, It's really important:(
The scenario is :
I have three table, Patient, patientAccount and Message.
Now, I am inserting values into tables Patient and Message first, and then after some time I am inserting values into PatientAccount Table.Now, the problem is in the software i am using sql with) i had this query:

```
select 
    * 
from Patient 
    join Message on Patient.GUID = Message.PatientGUID 
where Message.GUID = "..Data
```

and if I add PatientAccount in this query as well, like

```
select 
    * 
from Patient 
    join Message on Patient.GUID = Message.PatientGUID, PatientAccount 
where Message.GUID = "..Data
```

It becomes mandatory to add values to the `PatientAccount` table at the same moment when I am adding them to `Patient` and `Message` table, but what I really want is values to be taken up by query if there is data in the `PatientAccount` table, and if there is no values inserted into `patientAccount` table, It should pick up values from Patient and Message table only.
and I want all of it in one query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `outer join` for this purpose so that the select query doesn't depend on the PatientAccount table. Similar to the query below

```
SELECT * 
FROM   patient p 
       LEFT JOIN patientaccount pa 
              ON p.guid = pa.patientguid 
       LEFT JOIN message m 
              ON p.guid = m.patientguid 
WHERE  m.guid = "id"
```

This select query will always return records from the PatientAccount table but if there's no data for a specific Patient then the columns from the PatientAccount will be null

Comment: I think no need of left join for Message table, since the values first inserted into both Patient and Message table. But it'll also work fine.

Comment: it'll work either way, no matter what kind of join you specify